# Hakim Ziyech's looking for the gap that didn't exist. Is this sentence correct?

Tags: tense

I was watching the Chelsea VS Crystal Palace game today and I came across the commentary:

**Hakim Ziyech's looking for the gap that did not exist.**

The commentator was talking about a failed attempt to dribble.

Is this a correct sentence? Which one should I use there? Was or Is ?

**Hakim Ziyech is looking for the gap that do not exist.**

**Hakim Ziyech was looking for the gap that did not exist.**

**Hakim Ziyech is looking for the gap that did not exist.**

Are all the above sentences correct?

Comment: The first and third are the same. Commentary is often made in the present tense to keep a sense of excitement and immediacy.

Comment: ... perhaps "Hakim Ziyech is looking for a gap that does not exist". Commenters talk "off the cuff" and there is no guarantee that they speak grammatically correct English.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit messed up, but that's okay, because it's spoken commentary.

As the play happened the commentator says "Hakim Ziyech's looking for the gap..." and uses the present continuous as it is occurring "right now",  but then the play moves on (very quickly, football is a fast-moving sport) and by the time the commentator is finishing the sentence that play has finished and so the commentator has moved to the past tense "that did not exist".

This is an error of mismatched tenses.  However, the only way to avoid the error is to talk faster than the players can move - and that's not always possible.